# Writing MongoDB logs to a remote logging server

Tags: logging, mongodb, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to forward MongoDB logs from several remote servers to a central logging server. To do this, I changed my `mongod.conf` files to use syslog like so:

```
systemLog:
  destination: syslog
  syslogFacility: local3
```

I then configured rsyslog to forward messages like so:

```
if($syslogFacility-text == "local3") then{
  if($syslogTag contains "mongod") then{
    action(type="omfwd" target="MY.SYSLOG.SERVER.IP" port="PORT" protocol="udp")
    stop
  }
}
```

My logging server is configured to write any messages sent at that port to my central `mongod.log` file.

My question is; is there a better way to do this? For example, could I specify my logging server's IP/PORT in `mongod.conf` so I don't have to rely on each Mongo server's local rsyslog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem like it. According to the [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#systemLog.destination), the systemlog.destination option only accepts `file` and `syslog`.